# Existe alguma maneira de mostrar o resultado de uma query(mysqli) em forma de HTML?

Tags: php, query, mysqli

Já procurei intensivamente por uma solução para mostrar o resultado de uma query de mysqli dentro de uma  de html, mas não consigo encontrar nada. Vi que é possível apresentar o resultado através de uma  com a ajuda do fetch_assoc() no php, mas o que pretendo não necessita de ser mostrado dentro de uma table na minha perspetiva.
Em aixo está o código do que pretendo mostrar, já o testei em full php e mostra exatamente o que eu pretendo, o único obstáculo neste momento é conseguir incorporar esse mesmo resultado numa página HTML. Espero que me possam ajudar, cumprimentos.

```
     <?php
            require_once('connconf.php'); 

            $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $bdname) or die ('Connection Error');

            $sqlquery = "select ID_Vote from Votes where ID_Player = '1'"; 

            if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery))
                {

                    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                   echo $rowcount;   //this is the value i want to publish on a HTML <label>
                }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Tabela HTML completa

Se quiser exibir todos os dados de uma tabela, independente da *query*, tem essa solução mais elaborada, que mostra os resultados em formato de tabela, com os nomes do campo inclusive:

```
<?php
   require_once('connconf.php');
   $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $bdname) or die ( 'Connection Error' );
   $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM votes";

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery) or die ( mysqli_error( $conn ) );

   $header = true;
   echo '<table>';
   while( $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
      if( $header ) {
         foreach( $res as $campo => $valor ) {
            echo'<th>'.htmlentities( $campo ).'</th>';
         }
         $header = false;
      }
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach( $res as $campo => $valor ) {
         echo'<td>'.htmlentities( $valor ).'</td>';
      }
      echo '</tr>';
   }
   echo '</table>';
?>
```

Esta solução se adapta ao resultado da *query* independente do número de colunas, e já mostra os nomes dos campos corretamente no título da tabela.

**Exemplo:**

```
SELECT * FROM cadastro
```

Resultado

**`id     nome     documento`**   
`1     Roberto  129.132.111-33`
`2     Maria    212.332.718-83`
`3     César    417.229.873-12`
`...`

### Debug rápido

Se for apenas fazer um *debug* rápido, com poucos dados isso deve bastar:

```
<?php
    require_once('connconf.php'); 
    $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $bdname) or die ('Connection Error');
    $sqlquery = 'SELECT ID_Vote from Votes where ID_Player = 1'; 

    if( $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery) ) {
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r( mysqli_fetch_all( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) );
       echo '</pre>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponho que tudo está funcionando corretamente na sua **Query**, então para apresentar o resultado da variável `$rowcount`, em uma página html, você pode utilizar essa forma dentro de qualquer arquivo `.php` entre marcações `HTML`:

```
<label><?=$rowcount?></label>
```

Comment: Sim a query em si está correta, o problema é mesmo incorporar o resultado da query na página html...   testei essa linha de código como escreveste e começando por '<?php' sem me esquecer de fechar a '}' , mas continua a não mostrar.

Answer (score 0):

Outra possibilidade é embutir o html na seguinte forma.

```
Echo" <label>.$rowcount.</label>";
```

Comment: Rui, testei da maneira como referiste e o que me apareceu na pagina html foi isto: .$rowcount."; } ?> 

Depois testei desta forma: Echo "<label>".$rowcount."</label>";  e apareceu-me isto: ".$rowcount.""; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

Suponhamos que você esteja fazendo esta consulta esteja no mesmo arquivo que você quer mostrar o resultado no label, vamos chamá-lo apenas por questão de exemplo de mostraresultado.php

mostraresultado.php

```
     <?php
            require_once('connconf.php'); 

            $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $bdname) or die ('Connection Error');

            $sqlquery = "select ID_Vote from Votes where ID_Player = '1'"; 

            if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlquery))
                {

                    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
?>


                   <label><?php echo $rowcount;?></label>



<?php
                }

        ?>
```

A explicação é simples, você abre e fecha a "tag" do php sempre que quiser usar o html.